# How to query history in TFS?

Tags: tfs, history

I know every TFS work item shows it's history, but it's "find the difference" painful process... How can I query by history to see WHAT was actually changed? Assume I don't know what was changed, or that multiple items were changed, so I can't use an actual word or phrase

Comment: What do you mean by "query the history"? Using code, a tool in the UI.

Comment: I mean running a query/report within about history on a work item. For example, if I changed part of the body in a user story, I can see what was changed instead of a comparison table of the old and new values and have to find the differences between the two

Comment: So, finding all work items with a field that has changed or just given a work item, has the history changed? The first *might* be possible, the second one will have to be a VS Extension.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Visual Studio Online (VSO)? If so, you can use the REST API and specifically the [Updates method](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-work-item-updates-vsi) to see what changed in each revision of a work item. This will let you easily see the difference between two consecutive revisions.

If you want the changes between, say, revision 3 and revision 8 then you will need to aggregate the individual revision changes yourself to see the net difference between those two revisions.

If you're using an on-premise TFS server then you'll be using the .NET API. For that, have a look at this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243653/TFS-SDK-Work-Item-History-Visualizer-using-TFS-API) for more information, but the basics are that you need to do something like this to see all the revision information:

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
                    new Uri("https://tfs2010:8080/defaultcollection"));
var service = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
var workItem = service.GetWorkItem(id);
foreach (Revision revision in workItem.Revisions)
{
  foreach (Field field in wi.Fields)
  {
    //Do something interesting here instead
    var change = revision.Fields[field.Name].Value
  }
}
```

From there, it's up to you to work out what information you're actually interested in.

Comment: Thanks, Richard! I'm using on-premise TFS server. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the: [work item history visualizer](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx)

also, there's *get-tfsitemhistory*